# concatenate images from a matrix of images

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I have 4 images, each have width and height of 8. They belong inside a vector with shape `[4,8,8]`. I reshape the vector of images to become a matrix of images with shape `[2,2,8,8]`.

How can I concatenate the images from inside the matrix to produce a single image so that the shape becomes `[16,16]`? I want the images to be concatenated so that their x,y position from the matrix are maintained - essentially just stitching separate images together into a single image.

I have a feeling this could easily be done in `numpy`, maybe even `tensorflow`, but I'm open to any nice solution in python.

[image: visual of my problem]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.hstack` twice like so (slightly smaller arrays to make them printable):

```
import numpy as np

original = np.array([[np.arange(16).reshape(4,-1)]*2]*2)
combined = np.hstack(np.hstack(original))
print(combined)
```

wich gives:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 12 13 14 15]
 [ 0  1  2  3  0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7  4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 12 13 14 15]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `numpy.concatenate` with different axis. Here is an example with a reduced version using 4 images with shape `[2 2]`, which produces a `[4 4]`resulting image:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
b = np.array([[5, 6], [7, 8]])
c = np.array([[9, 10], [11, 12]])
d = np.array([[13, 14], [15, 16]])

ab = np.concatenate((a, b), axis=1)
cd = np.concatenate((c, d), axis=1)
abcd = np.concatenate((ab, cd), axis=0)

>>> print(abcd)
array([[ 1,  2,  5,  6],
       [ 3,  4,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 13, 14],
       [11, 12, 15, 16]])
>>> print(abcd.shape)
(4, 4)
```

Just adapt this code to yours, instead of using `a, b, c, d` concatenating images by the first dimension of your tensor, with something similar to `np.concatenate((t[0], t[1]), axis=1)` being `t` your tensor of shape `[4 8 8]`.

Otherwise, as other answers suggested you can use twice the `numpy.hstack` function twice, but I think that it's behaviour it's not that easily readable, even being less code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend doing this, because it's hardly readable, but just for the sake of numpy exercise you can make a grid of images with just `reshape()` and `transpose()` methods.

```py
import numpy as np

w_img = 3
h_img = 2
n_img = 4

images = (np.array([a + b for a in 'abcd' for b in '123456'])
            .reshape(n_img, h_img, w_img))

# A batch of 4 images 3x2
print(images)
#[[['a1' 'a2' 'a3']
#  ['a4' 'a5' 'a6']]
#
# [['b1' 'b2' 'b3']
#  ['b4' 'b5' 'b6']]
#
# [['c1' 'c2' 'c3']
#  ['c4' 'c5' 'c6']]
#
# [['d1' 'd2' 'd3']
#  ['d4' 'd5' 'd6']]]

# Making 2x2 grid
w_grid = 2
h_grid = 2

grid = images.reshape(h_grid, w_grid, h_img, w_img)  # axes: h_grid, w_grid, h_img, w_img
grid = grid.transpose([0, 2, 1, 3])                  # axes: h_grid, h_img, w_grid, w_img
grid = grid.reshape(4, 6)                            # axes: (h_grid * h_img), (w_grid * w_img)

print(grid)
#[['a1' 'a2' 'a3' 'b1' 'b2' 'b3']
# ['a4' 'a5' 'a6' 'b4' 'b5' 'b6']
# ['c1' 'c2' 'c3' 'd1' 'd2' 'd3']
# ['c4' 'c5' 'c6' 'd4' 'd5' 'd6']]
```